# Best practice fetching large amounts of data in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, database, next.js, content-management-system, fetch-api

I'm basically building a calendar of upcoming events for the year, each event acts like a blog post with its own thumbnail, and page. A pretty straightforward CMS set up.

I'm using FaunaDB and fetching in getStaticProps().

I then use component logic to break down the events into blocks of months and render a month at a time with an infinite scroll that re-renders and adds more months as you scroll down.

**If I end up with hundreds of events in the calendar will it cause getStaticProps to slow down, or break?**

**Is this the best practice for large amounts of data?**

**How much datas is too much to fetch in one go in getStaticProps?**

I get that I can just build components that make frequent client side fetch requests to my database – but surely this defeats the point of using Next.js, (plus I need getStaticPaths() to generate the pages for each event.

On a side note, there will be POST route that adds a new calendar event and triggers a rebuild – will next.js build the entire site from scratch, or is it clever enough to only build the new calendar event.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I end up with hundreds of events in the calendar will it cause getStaticProps to slow down, or break?

Millions of events? Sure, it will. I suggest using an approach that scales. You could just get away with hundreds of records, but when you get millions of records, you'll have to take some actions eventually.

> Is this the best practice for large amounts of data?

No. Normally you do not need all data in `getStaticPaths`. You should just fetch enough data for initial render in `getStaticPaths`, and re-fetch more data on client side whenever you need them.
In your case, you don't need to fetch all the events in `getStaticPaths`. You could just fetch events of this month (and maybe last and next month) in `getStaticPaths`, and re-fetch more events whenever user moves to other month(think of Google Calendar).

> How much datas is too much to fetch in one go in getStaticProps?

It depends. When you notice something is slow, it's a good indication that it is too much.

Comment: Thanks! I doubt I'll ever get to millions, so I can likely get by with just getStaticProps, but probably best practice to build with scaling in mind anyway.